# CSS Background on hover

Tags: javascript, css

I would still love some help with changing the background-image on span hover.
If anybody could help me with that. I provided the full code of the website, down below.

Here is the Full code of the website.

[Pastebin CSS](http://pastebin.com/0CK8Tgej)

[Pastebin JavaScript](http://pastebin.com/TqApd5Mj)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at jquery `.hover();` and `.css();` or `.hover();` and `.addClass();` and `.removeClass();`.
This should give you exactly what you are looking for. You could even throw in `.animate();` to make it a less brutal of a transition.

Here is a small example:

*JQUERY:*

```
$(function(){

  $('.text1').hover(function(){
    $('body').css('background-color', 'blue');
  });

});
```

Put this code inside a file named 'anything-you-want.js' and include it into the top of your html `<head>` section using the `<script src="anything-you-want.js">` tag to link it to the new js file you created. Also if you are using `.css();`, like the example, make sure you give your body a `background-color` inside your css or else it will not work. Also make sure you link the JQuery Library inside your html `<head>` tag like you did for the anything-you-want.js file.
Here is the link to it..
[Jquery Library](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.2.min.js)

EDIT: (added animate)

```
$(function(){

  $('.text1').hover(function() {
    $('body').stop().animate({
      backgroundColor:'rgb(255, 60, 0)'
    }, 300);
  }, function () {
    $('body').stop().animate({
      backgroundColor:'rgb(134, 33, 0)'
    }, 100);
  });

});
```

Comment: I have my main background selected in my CSS body element. But this JQUERY, Doesn't override that?

Comment: This must must mean you either have the same color in your css or one of your script links in your html `<head>` isnt linking correctly. Double check your script links and if you want you can always edit your question and post the code so we can see what is going on exactly.

Comment: And how would i add a .fadeIn(); Still pretty new to JS

Comment: You should actually go with using `.animate();` using the Jquery.ui.js library. Its a different library from the one you are currently using. [Jquery UI](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js) This is the Library for animate. add that into your html head script.

Comment: I can't program javascript or anything. So i don't know what you're talking about :p

Comment: Ok, just check my edit. Remember to add the script link inside your html head like you did for Jquery.js and anything-you-want.js files. I would really recommend learning Jquery as it can really make life alot easier as a web developer!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using pure JS, checkout onmouseover. You can read up on it at this [W3 site](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp).

```
In HTML:
<element onmouseover="myScript">

In JavaScript:
object.onmouseover=function(){myScript};

In JavaScript, using the addEventListener() method:
object.addEventListener("mouseover", myScript);
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this using JQuery or Javascript.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type = "text/css">
            body
            {
                background: url(http://www.programmingfacts.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/change-parent-bg-color-hover-child.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
            }

            h1: hover
            {
                background: url(back6.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
            }
            .hover
              {
                background-image: url('http://s5.postimg.org/8jj7nydhz/Background_main.jpg');
              }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() {
            $('h1').hover(function() {
                $('body').addClass('hover');
            }, function(){
                $('body').removeClass('hover');
            });
          });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>
            Future Text.<br>
            <span class="text1">Text1</span>, <span class="text2">Text2</span>, <span class="text3">Text3</span>, <span class="text4">Text4</span>.
        </h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.test{
background-image:     url("https://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/background-wallpapers-32_NRz0mTd.jpg");

}
```

```html
<div class="test">
<form action="search.php" method="GET">
    <input type="text" name="query" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
</div>
```

```
}
enter code here
```